# Push keyboard higher then adjustPan

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, push, adjustpan

I was wondering if there's a way to push my scrollView  even higher up then that `"android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`does. It looks kinda cramped the way it's currently. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvIO3.png)

Heres a picture

Answer (score 1):

you should use

`"android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustUnspecified"`

**Layout** .....check ---> **layout_height** for both

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:background="#F7F7F7"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

     <EditText 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:hint="New Message"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/round_corner_msg_box"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Setting it to "adjustUnspecified" doesn't change it. Not sure what you mean by "Layout .....check ---> layout_height for both"